# Why are Chrome exceptions for third-party cookies not working (results in inability to use Disqus)?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, disqus

So Disqus has not been working for me for some time, and they finally, handily, added a little  notification that it's due to third party cookies being blocked. Great, I said, let's take care of that.

So I added an exception for disqus.com to Chrome's preferences, but it does not seem to be working. I did this vis Preferences -> Advanced -> Content Settings -> Manage Exceptions, where I have added an 'allow' exception for `disqus.com`. I have third-party cookies otherwise blocked.

Disqus still doesn't work, though, giving me the same error on every site that it's unable to work with third party cookies. The error persists even if I go to disqus.com and login, then revisit a site.

Why might disqus be failing here?

Answer (score 12):

The reason is that you have to tell Chrome to allow 3rd party cookies for **subdomains** of disqus.com as well. So just set the exception to this instead: `[*.]disqus.com`.

Comment: I have done this. Chrome auto-sets [*.]disqus.com to disqus.com.

Comment: Did you make sure to include the brackets? Without them Chrome resets the entry to disqus.com. http://cl.ly/2x2l1e0X322J001C0P3Q

Comment: I did. My version believes this is invalid, and auto-corrects it to disqus.com. http://cl.ly/0m3Y0B082M1Q0m1g3c2X

Comment: Thanks. That actually worked. I am on chrome 20.X stable / Win7. @bhuga Looks like your on mac, might be an bug on the os x build of chrome.

Comment: I've had this problem since at least chrome 18, and the problem persists with a 20.X build :/

Comment: [*.]disqus.com for Chrome on Mac version 23.0.1271.64 is working for me (whereas plain disqus.com did not)

Answer (score -1):

Disqus requires you to accept third party cookies.  If you want to use it, you have to turn them on and take your chances with the bad guys who use them for nefarious purposes.

Comment: understood, but why would it not work with the exception enabled?